# when i put <fh> value above 40 ,it just give output for <otp> then didn't give <fp> [means fp = reg + otp] .just give [fp = fh * fr]

Tags: python, conditional-statements

i need to get last print output for < fp >. {fp =  reg + otp}.
if i cut and paste this fp from if and paste  outside then give reg + otp.

```
xh = input('enter hours: ')
xr = input('enter rate:')

fh = float(xh)
fr = float(xr)

if fh > 40:
    print("overtime")
    reg = fr * fh
    otp = (fh - 40) * (fr * 0.5)
    print(otp)
    fp = reg + otp

else:
    print("reguler")
fp = fh * fr

print('this is your paymant: ',fp)

# it didn't give output for fp = reg + otp
```

Comment: `fp = fh * fr` must be indented as part of `else` blok

Answer (score 0):

The `fp = fh * fr` statement needs to be indented so it is part of the `else` statement.  Otherwise, it will overwrite your overtime computation.

```
else:
    print("regular")
    fp = fh * fr
```

Comment: thanks tim robert